# Transform and flatten List of disjunctions

Tags: scala, scalaz

```
case class Errs(errors: List[Err]) 
case class Err(exceptionMessage: String, customMessage: String, statusCode: Int, extraInfo: Option[String] = None)
```

One of the functions returning `val result = List[\/[Errs, Boolean]]`

In order to transform/sequence and flatten `result` following passes are done

`val finalRes: \/[Errs, Boolean] = result.map(_.swap).sequenceU.map(x => Errs(x.map(_.errors).flatten)).swap`

This looks inelegant and performance intensive (given number of passes it has to via multiple `map` calls etc)

Is there a combinator in `scalaz` which can make this more elegant with less number of passes or this demands writing a custom function?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `ValidationNel`? It makes accumulating errors a lot nicer. Also at a glance, you can always mechanically rewrite `foo.map(bar).sequenceU` as `foo.traverseU(bar)`.

Comment: @TravisBrown thanks. Actually sparsely we do use ValidationNel (for error accumulating cases). In this particular case there is `map` applied to a `List` of items and mapping function returns `disjunction` hence transformed `List` becomes `List[\/[Errs, Boolean]]`. I did use `traverseU` to remove some `map` followed by `sequenceU`.latest snippet ` res.traverseU(_.swap).map(errs => new Errs(errs)).swap`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use a `traverseU`, as suggested by Travis Brown.

After that, a call to `map` followed by a call to `flatten` can be written with a `flatMap`.

```
val finalRes: \/[Errs, Boolean] = result.traverseU(_.swap).map(x => Errs(x.flatMap(_.errors))).swap
```

Moreover, you may consider using a type alias for `Errs`.

```
type Errs = List[Err]
```

So, the code is simpler (less boxing/unboxing) :

```
val finalRes: \/[Errs, Boolean] = result.traverseU(_.swap).map(_.flatten).swap
```